# Xcode - Google Street View api 3D panorama

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, photos

My goal is to use the Google Street View API to display a full pledged panorama scrollable street view image to the user. Basically the API provides me with many images where I can vary the direction, height, zoom, location etc. I can retrieve all these and hope to stitch them together and view it. The first question is, do you know any resources that demoes this full google street view demo working? Where a user can swipe around to move street view around, just like in that old iOS 5 Map Street View thing that I am sure we all miss...

If not, I will be basically downloading hundreds of photos that differ in vertical and horizontal direction. Is there a library or API or resource or method where I can stitch all these photos together to make a big panorama and make it so the user can swipe to view the big panorama on the tiny iPhone screen?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Just to be clear about this as someone that doesn't directly know the Street View API, they've got the 3d maths running at their end so if URL fetches magically became instant you'd be able to run what people would recognise as street view by just supplying new parameters every time the camera moves? And your question is, what can you do to cache a very small subset of the available queries and perform your own 3d maths on client to fill in the gaps?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, what I have done is I have created an app where you can press left and right buttons to change the paremeters of 'direction' which works but I would like a stitched together 180 degree version

Comment: @Tommy Exactly, I need a 3d maths on client to fill the gaps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I threw together a quick implementation to do a lot of this as a demo for you.  There are some excellent open source libraries out there that make an amateur version of StreetView very simple.  You can check out my demo on GitHub: https://github.com/ocrickard/StreetViewDemo

You can use the heading and pitch parameters from the Google StreetView API to generate tiles.  These tiles could be arranged in a UIScrollView as both Bilal and Geraud.ch suggest.  However, I really like the JCTiledScrollView because it contains a pretty nice annotation system for adding pins on top of the images like Google does, and its datasource/delegate structure makes for some very straight forward image handling.

The meaty parts of my implementation follow:

```
- (UIImage *)tiledScrollView:(JCTiledScrollView *)scrollView imageForRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column scale:(NSInteger)scale
{
    float fov = 45.f / scale;

    float heading = fmodf(column*fov, 360.f);
    float pitch = (scale - row)*fov;

    if(lastRequestDate) {
        while(fabsf([lastRequestDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < 0.1f) {
            //continue only if the time interval is greater than 0.1 seconds
        }
    }

    lastRequestDate = [NSDate date];

    int resolution = (scale > 1.f) ? 640 : 200;

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=%dx%d&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=%f&heading=%f&pitch=%f&sensor=false", resolution, resolution, fov, heading, pitch];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] options:0 error:&error];
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading image:%@", error);
    }
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    //Distort image using GPUImage
    {
        //This is where you should try to transform the image.  I messed around
        //with the math for awhile, and couldn't get it.  Therefore, this is left
        //as an exercise for the reader... :)

        /*
        GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
        GPUImageTransformFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
        [stillImageFilter forceProcessingAtSize:image.size];

        //This is actually based on some math, but doesn't work...
        //float xOffset = 200.f;

        //CATransform3D transform = [ViewController rectToQuad:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height) quadTLX:-xOffset quadTLY:0 quadTRX:(image.size.width+xOffset) quadTRY:0.f quadBLX:0.f quadBLY:image.size.height quadBRX:image.size.width quadBRY:image.size.height];
        //[(GPUImageTransformFilter *)stillImageFilter setTransform3D:transform];

        //This is me playing guess and check...
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform.m34 = fabsf(pitch) / 60.f * 0.3f;

        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, pitch*M_PI/180.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.f/cosf(pitch*M_PI/180.f), sinf(pitch*M_PI/180.f) + 1.f, 1.f);
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.f, 0.1f * sinf(pitch*M_PI/180.f), 0.f);

        [stillImageFilter setTransform3D:transform];


        [stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
        [stillImageFilter prepareForImageCapture];
        [stillImageSource processImage];

        image = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
         */
    }

    return image;
}
```

Now, in order to get the full 360 degree, infinite scrolling effect Google has, you would have to do some trickery in the observeValueForKeyPath method where you observe the contentOffset of the UIScrollView.  I've started implementing this, but did not finish it.  The idea is that when the user reaches either the left or right side of the view, the `contentOffset` property of the scrollView is pushed to the opposite side of the scrollView.  If you can get the content to align properly, and you set up the contentSize just right, this should work.

Finally, I should note that the Google StreetView system has a limit of 10 images/second, so you have to throttle your requests or the IP address of the device will be blacklisted for a certain amount of time (my home internet is now blacked out from StreetView requests for the next few hours 'cause I didn't understand this at first).

Comment: Haha awesome! In school right now, I will check this out later

Comment: Awesome! This is an excellent demo that I will work my way around using! Seriously awesome!

Comment: This is so amazing and I cant believe you put this together or helped me find this so another 100 reputation tomorow!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use UIScrollView, set its clipSubviews property to true, add all the images to the UIScrollView and the UIScrollView's contentsOffset according to the images.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method described on this post: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

You will have to make some factory to transform images to the good size and to your viewport (iPhone/iPad). And then add some buttons where you can clicked to go to the next place.

Unfortunately, if you want to go to a globe version (instead of a tube one), I think you'll need to go full openGL to display images in this 3D surface.

Comment: Maybe the code is a bit old but you need the principle and then you can go for yourself.

Comment: Yeah.... I won't be directly copy and paste in, I just hope the jist, Apis etc works

Comment: And the properties and methods

Comment: Hi geruad.ch, this is not exactly what I want, what I am asking for is something similar to google street view, except only horizontal scroll..... it stitches the Photos together and you can scroll around to view the whole Panorama but it doesn't collapse on one another... think of it like this.... take a Panorama on your scratched uP iPhone 5 and zoom in then scroll around, that is a similar effect to what i need (assuming you have aPPle Products :)